# How to find an element by attribute using QueryPath

Tags: attr, querypath

I need to find all tables with `width=230`

So far I have:

```
foreach($qp->top('table')->get() as $table) {
    $width = $table->attr('width');
}
```

But I get a `"Call to undefined method DOMElement::attr()"` error.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
$table->find('[width="230"]');
```

Comment: I'm trying 'select[name="group_id"]' and just '[name="group_id"]', and also without the quotes, and I get nothing. Only works if I use 'select', but that is without the attribute condition.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, $table is a [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php), so probably you can do

```
$width = $table->getAttribute('width);
```